Has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'
I was facing the CORS error while deploying my amazon-clone react project in vercel.com
Error:
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://amazon-clone- 
rvom.vercel.app/create-checkout-session' from origin 
'https://amazon-clone-ecru-seven.vercel.app' has been blocked by 
CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present 
on the requested resource.

POST https://amazon-clone-rvom.vercel.app/create-checkout- 
session net::ERR_FAILED 500 (Internal Server Error)

Client:
  const checkoutSession = await axios.post(
    "https://amazon-clone-rvom.vercel.app/create-checkout- 
  session",
    {
      cart,
      email: user.email,
    }
  );

Server:
require("dotenv").config();
const cors = require("cors");
const stripe = require("stripe")(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY);
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
app.use(express.json()); 
app.use(cors());

app.post("/create-checkout-session", async (req, res) => {
const { cart, email } = req.body;

stripe code goes here...
}

Headers Network Tab
network_pic1
network_pic2
I have tried as many solutions from online but I couldn't solve the CORS errors.
I had spent more hours trying to solve this error and its frustrating me.
Please help me to solve the error

Please embed your code in the question, not a picture of your code. I had a quick look but FYI origins don't end in a slash. It should be in the form protocol://host not protocol://host/

@Evert Thanks for your response. Despite applying protocol://host, I continued to encounter the same issue.

Thanks for embedding the code! On the server-side you use both a cors middleware, and you write your own manually. You should only do 1 of these two, not both. So I would suggest you remove your own code and just use cors(). On the client-side there is no point in specifying Access-Control-Allow-Origin. Remove that too. After you made these changes, if this didn't solve the problem share the exact full error you got in the question, and update your code so we can look at the correct, latest version.

It might also help to show what headers you got back from this endpoint on the network tab.

What are the respective Web origins of your client and server?

@Evert Once again, thanks for your response. I have modified my code as per your suggestion, but I am still facing the same error. I have updated my code in the question.

@jub0bs, I appreciate your response,
Client web origin: https://amazon-clone-ecru-seven.vercel.app/
Server web origin : https://amazon-clone-rvom.vercel.app/

I believe you should figure out why you're getting a 500 response. Once you do, your CORS issue will likely go away.

@jub0bs Okay, I will figure out 500 response. In development (localhost), I didn't get the CORS error, but the same code after deployment gets the CORS error. In the deployment code, I only made changes to the client and server origin.

I concur with jub0bs. The CORS middleware probably doesn't get a chance to run.

After thoroughly reviewing my code, I was unable to determine the precise cause of the error, so I relocated the server code and included it on the client side in a different module, which I then imported in order to use it. Now my code is working fine without any error.
Thank you so much jub0bs & Evert for your timely responses.
